# Excel Make conditional formmating appear as a list in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset and have two extreme numbers which I would use conditonal formatting to work out if the numbers in the data set dont fit into the criteria, as in the formula I would use below.

```
=OR(B3<$E$8,B3>$E$7)
```

Im wondering is their any way of making the list of cells which dont fit the criteria to appear as a list, in a cell.

For example, if I had a list of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 and the two numbers were 3 and 7 then the fromula would gerneate this output:

```
1,2,8,9
```

Answer (score 1):

Enter the following **U**ser **D**efined **F**unction in a standard module:

```
Public Function MakeAList(rng As Range, U As Long, L As Long) As String
  Dim r As Range, s As String
  For Each r In rng
    If r.Value < L Or r.Value > U Then
      s = s & "," & r.Value
    End If
  Next r
  MakeAList = Mid(s, 2)
End Function
```

and then use it with your range of values:

[image]

**NOTE:**

The first argument is the range of values.
The second argument is the upper limit.
The third argument is the lower limit.

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

=MakeAList(A1:A100,B1,C1)

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
=LEFT(D2;FIND(G2;D2)-1)&RIGHT(D2;LEN(D2)-FIND(H2;D2)-1)
```

where:

```
D2 - 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
G2 - 3
H2 - 7
```

result:

```
1,2,8,9
```

best - AB

Comment: i thought this was the question